# BB10 Show System Dialog in QThread Slot is not working

Tags: qthread, blackberry-cascades, qdialog

Im trying to show dialog in thread, it shows for the first time.

If I dont use `isAlert`, it shows 10-15 dialogs

Here is my code:

```
bool isAlert;
void MyThread::ShowAlert(const QString &message)
{
    if(!isAlert){
        SystemDialog *myDialog = new SystemDialog(tr("OK"), 0); 
        myDialog->setTitle(tr("Alert")); 
        myDialog->setBody(message); 
        myDialog->setDismissAutomatically(true);
        bool success = connect(myDialog,
            SIGNAL(finished(bb::system::SystemUiResult::Type)),
            this,
            SLOT(onDialogFinished(bb::system::SystemUiResult::Type)));
         if(success)
            myDialog->show();
    }
}
void MyThread::onDialogFinished(bb::system::SystemUiResult::Type){
    isAlert=false;
}
MyThread::run(){
    while(true){        
        ...
        if(...){
            ShowAlert("Some text");
        }
    }
}
```

onDialogFinished is not working at all.

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 0):

try to user myDialog->exec() instead of show. Solved my problem